# Can I pay someone to do the work I am payed for doing?

Tags: salary, hiring

I have to create a software tool, that helps some of my colleagues. My boss told me to do that, but after almost two weeks, I still am not really getting behind it.

Would it be legal to pay someone to create the program for me? There are no personal or internal infos involved, but in the end, my Boss is paying me for doing it, while I am paying someone (less, because they won't need 2 weeks) to do it, giving me a win.

PS: I wouldn't get a financial win, as I would have to pay the other one with the salary i get, but that still gives me "mySalary - SalaryToPayForProgram = money i get for nothing"

PPS: This is just something I thought about. I never had the intention to outsource my work

Comment: "Would it be legal to pay someone to create the program for me?" Ask a lawyer, and I VTC as you are asking for legal advice.

Comment: Is this just from lazines or lack of ability?

Comment: There was an article on The Onion "It turns out everyone is outsourcing their work to a single dude in Bangalore".

Comment: You're not the first one to have this idea... https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-21043693

Comment: Just an anecdote, I know a guy in banking who was making on the order of 1/4 million bucks a year, who was flat sacked for doing this. And he wasn't doing it out of laziness or whatever, just a desire to be fasttrack innovative.

Comment: @LaurentS. 7 years later and he could just say he's working from home :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No absolutely not. It's a perfect way to get fired so hard your ass will leave marks on the outside pavement, quite apart from much further legal trouble.

They don't hire (anonymous person who codes) they hire you. Your history, your references, *you*.

If things go wrong, who do they ask for? If someone slips some malicious code into the codebase who will they grill?

If a customer's factory catches fire because of a missed semicolon and your company is held liable they will be insured because they vetted *you*. If it turns out that you passed on the coding to (unvetted anonymous third party) you can bet your ass the insurance company and yours will team up to make your life living hell.

what you *can* do is ask your manager. make the case that your talents are better used elsewehere and that the grunt-coding can be outsourced. Be prepared to be shot down though but your boss can explain why.

Comment: There is also a primitive legal matter. Work for hier contracts are to a specific person. You are not a freelancer that can send an employee or subcontractor - you are hired AS PERSON to provide work for a specific amount of time per day.

Answer (score 11):

Whether or not it's strictly *legal*, it's a phenomenally bad idea.

There are tons of ways it could go wrong. And even if it all goes right, you're going to be stuck with a software application that everyone assumes you wrote and can adapt/extend/debug as needed. So you'll either have to learn how to do it eventually (in which case you may as well do it now), or you'll have to eventually come clean (at which point you'll likely be fired), or you'll have to quit before it gets to that point.

If you can't do it yourself then you should tell your boss that and suggest the company hire someone to create the program (the same way you were thinking of doing).

Comment: "it's a phenomenally bad idea" indeed, and that's not hyperbole